# Java: How to strip text content from HTML tags?

Tags: java, html, regex, parsing

Lets consider this html code:

```
<html<body><p><b>Hi there</b></p><a href="a.com">click here</a></html>
```

what I want from this html code is to remove the content between html tags and retrieve the html structure. Like this:

```
<html<body><p><b></b></p><a href="a.com"></a></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this satisfy?

```
txt.replaceAll(">[^<]*<","><")
```